# Running R-Notebook on an AWS-VPC with no internet acess

Tags: r, amazon-vpc, rstudio-server, rnotebook

I am running RStudio-server on an AWS-VPC with no internet access. When I try to open a new **R-Notebook** it gets stuck on the loading wheel screen. I have two hypothesis:

1. RStudio tries to connect to the internet (for some reason). Since it can't, it gets stuck;
2. Dependency problem.

Everything else works fine (normal R scripts).

The machine that serves RStudio is an EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16 and I'm connecting through a Windows Server 2008 instance in the same VPC.

Any alternative hypothesis?

Comment: What OS?  Are you opening RStudio from the same machine that is running RStudio-server?

Comment: You can't able to connect EC2 instance from Windows Server 2008 instance right?

Answer (score 1):

It's both. It's probably missing the dependencies, so it tries to connect to the internet to download them. The wait occurs as it is waiting for a response from the remote server before timing out.

[`rmarkdown`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html) has the following dependencies:

- tools
- utils
- knitr (≥ 1.14)
- yaml (≥ 2.1.5)
- htmltools (≥ 0.3.5)
- caTools
- evaluate (≥ 0.8)
- base64enc
- jsonlite
- rprojroot
- methods

If you wait for it to time out, it will tell you which packages are missing.

The waiting period can be mitigated by setting:

```
options(repos = NULL)
```

This will immediately bring the error message (and stop the URI lookup)

I haven't tried setting the repos to point to a local CRAN repos (made using miniCRAN) but the safest way is the set it to `NULL` and then manually install the missing repos via `R CMD INSTALL <package.tar.gz>`